# Use MakeCert to Authenticate

Tags: c#

I am doing a project on Verifying/Authenticating School Certificates to make sure that its real. Anyone has any ideas how to do it using MakeCert.exe in C#

Comment: The scope of this question is too broad.

Comment: I will add a more detailed question soon. Thanks anw.

Answer (score 0):

here are the steps to [Using Makecert.exe to Build a Certificate Chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731899.aspx)